# I want to change the icon color of one layer in leaflet, I have two point ,layers all appearing as blue default icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have two points layers as Geojson files that I added to my leaflet map. The issue is that they all appear as the blue default icon. I want to change one to red. How do I do this?

**Code**

```html
<body>
  <h1>Settlement Map</h1>
  <div id="map">
    <script>
      var map = L.map('map').setView([-34.06001, 18.66321], 13);
      var addressLayer = L.geoJSON(address, {
        color: 'red'
      }).addTo(map);
      var EPLayer = L.geoJSON(EP).addTo(map);
    </script>
  </div>
  <body/>
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have done yet.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: See https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ and https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

Comment: <body>
 <h1>Settlement Map</h1>
  <div id = "map">
   <script>
   var map = L.map('map').setView([-34.06001, 18.66321], 13);
   var addressLayer = L.geoJSON(address, {color:'red'}).addTo(map);
   var EPLayer = L.geoJSON(EP).addTo(map);
         
  </script>
 </div>
 
<body/>

Comment: I am super new to this, I actually don't know how to add code properly. it keeps saying error with indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pointToLayer function

```
L.geoJSON(json,{
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        switch (feature.properties.country) {
            case 'at': return L.marker(latlng, {icon: redIcon});
            case 'de': return L.marker(latlng, {icon: greenIcon});
            default: return L.marker(latlng);
        } 
    }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/3ycm6dzv/